# DAX How to return a table based on a condition - workaround for IF to return a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to return DAX table based on a condition? The IF function cannot return a table in DAX.

```
IF( 1=1, table_1, table_2 )
```

It raises an error: *The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.*

I would like to use a slicer to choose between multiple tables, which table later can be used for the alternating dynamic filter context in CALCULATE.

```
CALCULATE( [Measure], 
   IF( Condition, 
       table_1,
       table_2
   )
)
```

To make the problem more challenging I would like the table_1 and table_2 to have different set of columns. So combination of UNION and FILTER function won't do.

```
UNION(
   FILTER( table_1,     condition ),
   FILTER( table_2, NOT condition)
)
```

As a possible approach, we might pick up a measure based on a slicer choice:

```
IF( Slicer_Selection_Condition, 
      [M1], // Measure with filter set 1
      [M2]  // Measure with filter set 2
   )
```

But I do not want to go this way because it multiplies the number of required measures for each slicer combination.

If we could surpass the IF limitation, we could very usefully apply it. Imagine, we have a slicer to choose a measure among [Quantity], [Value], [Cost]. And we also have another slicer to choose the filter set. We could handle it with a one measure:

```
CALCULATE(
   SWITCH( Measure_Slicer, 1, [Quantity], 2, [Value],  [Cost] ), // measure choice
   SWITCH( Filter_Slicer,  1, table_1,    2, table_2,  table_3 ) // filter choice
)
```

---

Here is a table to recreate problem:

```
Table = 
DATATABLE (
    "Color", STRING,
    "Shape", STRING,
    "Quantity", INTEGER,
    "Value",    INTEGER,
    {
        { "Red"   , "Circle"  , 1, 10 },
        { "Red"   , "Triangle", 1, 10 },
        { "Blue"  , "Circle"  , 1, 10 },
        { "Blue"  , "Triangle", 1, 10 },
        { "Yellow", "Square"  , 1, 10 }
    }
)
```

And measures:

```
M_Quantity = SUM( 'Table'[Quantity] )
```

```
M_Value    = SUM( 'Table'[Value] )
```

```
Desired Measure = 
VAR Measure_Slicer = 1   // Either 1 OR 2
VAR Filter_Slicer  = 1   // Either 1 OR 2

VAR table_1 = SUMMARIZE( 'Table', 'Table'[Color] )
VAR table_2 = SUMMARIZE( 'Table', 'Table'[Color], 'Table'[Shape] )

RETURN
CALCULATE(
   SWITCH( Measure_Slicer, 1, [M_Quantity], [M_Value]), // Measure choice
   SWITCH( Filter_Slicer,  1, table_1     , table_2  )  // Filter choice
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I think the solution is possible. Eventually I have not tested it too much but I share the concept in case you may find it useful.
The idea is that the filter conditions in the filter tables have to be combined with a boolean factor that can make one of the two filter tables valid (the other will be just empty).

```
VAR __my_boolean = Filter_Slicer  = 1
//__my_boolean is true when the Filter_Slicer  = 1, otherwise __my_boolean is false
VAR __filter_A = FILTER(table, table_1 && __my_boolean)
//this filter table will only contain data when __my_boolean is true
VAR __filter_B = FILTER(table, table_2 && NOT(__my_boolean))
//this filter table will only contain data when __my_boolean is false

RETURN
CALCULATETABLE(table
,UNION(__filter_A,__filter_B))
```

So as you see, this is similar to what you mentioned as "combination of UNION and FILTER function won't do", but it has been taken one step further to consolidate the distinct filter tables (table_1 and table_2) to a uniform set of columns. If you find it useful, please leave a sign :). Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to test it right now. Is your solution designed to pass the test of different columns set in _filter_A and filter_B?

Answer (score 0):

Here, a solution for one slicer which lets the user **choose between different measures**. How to select different data tables, is something I am also curious about :)

Based on your table `Table` above and the two measures `M_Quantity` and `M_Value`, the only things you need to add are:

1. A table which includes the possibilities for the selection:

   ```
   choice_measures = 
   DATATABLE (
       "Id", INTEGER,
       "Use", STRING,
       {
         { 1, "Quantity"},
         { 2, "Value"   }
       }
   )
   ```
2. One more measure:

   ```
   M_Measure = 
   VAR MySelection = SELECTEDVALUE(choice_measures[Id], "Show all") RETURN 
   SWITCH(
       TRUE(), 
       MySelection = 1, [M_Quantity], 
       MySelection = 2, [M_Value], 
       ""
   )
   ```
3. A slicer for `choice_measures[Id]` where the user can choose between the two measures and, finally, a card where the chosen measure is displayed via `M_Measure`. Then, it will look like this:

[image]

**Good luck!** Looking forward to the answers of other users on the second part of your question learning how to switch between different data tables!

Comment: I have mentioned this approach in my question as non-satisfactory solution: `IF(Slicer_Selection_Condition, [M1], [M2] )` It is not a workaround to conditional return of a table. Nevertheless, thank you for a try.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I have arrived at the following conclusions:

1. Using `SWITCH` or similar to declare a measure to be used within `CALCULATE` is not valid syntax. For these types of applications, calculation groups exist, where you code your measures with a placeholder `SELECTEDMEASURE`.
2. Arbitrarily shaped filters are allowed in DAX, but apparently not conditionally. It appears passing filter tables to `CALCULATE` conditionally, either by `IF` or `SWITCH` throws errors. In dax.do this error points to a lack of column declaration, but this is not needed for a filter table passed outside of a conditional construct. I suspect this is due to data lineage not being preserved through a such a construct.

Comment: I want conditionally returned table as a filter in a DAX measure. Completely different story than you are mentioning in your answer. That is true you wrote but is not relevant to my question. You can have dynamically calculated DAX tables, sometimes stored in VAR to use in a measure. Please check the desired measure pattern in my question.

Comment: You are correct - I was too hasty. I will have another look.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it is likely that data lineage is not preserved through `IF` and `SWITCH` conditionals.

Comment: So you almost arrived to the point of my question. Almost, because in my question I am already further, because I present a workaround to return tables conditionally through UNION function and mutually excluding conditions. Note that I am aware of limitations but I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Workarounds do not exist until somebody finds a way :-)

Comment: Interestingly, the only question you pose in your submission has already been answered, by yourself. This is not a limitation with `IF` return types at all (since you can easily return tables conditionally) but a limitation of data lineage. Filter tables without data lineage are not suitable for filters in `CALCULATE`. I don’t think you’re any closer to solving this with `UNION`, since even if data lineage is preserved, you will pass blank columns as a filter. The workaround here is to write more measures - which you already know, and conditionally invoke them.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes we need detail row exp to return diff tables based on double click so thank you for union and filter variant when diff tables have the same qnty of columns, but for diff qnty of columns what do you think about this variant?

```
EVALUATE

VAR x =
    { (
        "test",
        ( IF( 1 = 1, 1, 0 ) ) -- change with measure? union & filter
    )
    }
    
VAR y =
    {
        ("test", 1, "C1", 100),
        ("test", 1, "C1", 200),
        ("test", 1, "C1", 300)
    } -- maybe addcolumns() to the real table
    
RETURN

    NATURALINNERJOIN(x,y)
```